# Why do I get 'cps-transformed unexpectedly' message on Scala continuations

Tags: scala, continuations

So I have the following code (doing exercise 4 of that [tutorial](http://www.is.ocha.ac.jp/~asai/cw2011tutorial/main-e.pdf)):

```
import scala.util.continuations._
object Main {
  def times(lst: List[Int]): Int@cps[Int] = lst match {
    case Nil => 1
    case 0 :: rest => shift{(_: Int=>Int) => 0 } * times(rest)
    case first :: rest => first * times(rest)
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(reset{times(List(0 to 1000: _*))})
  }
}
```

I'm compiling with scala 2.10.0 and I got the following warning:

```
CWSO.scala:3: warning: expression matchEnd9(x: Int){
  x
} is cps-transformed unexpectedly
  def times(lst: List[Int]): Int@cps[Int] = lst match {
                                            ^
one warning found
```

Is there something wrong in the way I wrote that code? What should I do to avoid the warning? The code seems to be doing the correct thing (multiplies numbers and aborts early when 0 is the first element).

Comment: I'm not sure, but it could be related to your expression evaluating differently on different cases, so the compiler warns that the match value `lst` should not always be actually *cps-transformed*. This is just a guess. You could try to wrap with a `shift` in all the cases to check if the warning disappears.

Comment: @pagoda_5b, I did try to wrap with a shift `shiftUnit[Int, Int, Int](1)` as well as for `shiftUnit[Int, Int, Int](first) * times(rest)` and still got the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This smells like a bug, and was reported as such: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6817